# "Resource not found for the segment 'teams'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to access Teams-Ressourcec via the Microsoft graph-API. I seem to hit a wall with that. The app has the required permissions (as listed in MS documentation)

Queries I've tried:
A simple GET:

```
  string querystring = "api-version=1.6";
    var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/teams/" + TeamID+ "/channels?" + querystring;
    Console.WriteLine(uri);
    HTTPClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
    var GetResult = await HTTPClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

This one works with delegated permissions in Graph Explorer (v1.0) however it uses delegate user permissions, and not app permissions.

POST for migration team reation:

```
        string querystring = "api-version=1.6";
        var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/teams?" + querystring;
        HTTPClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        HttpRequestMessage Content = new HttpRequestMessage();
        Content.Content = new StringContent("{   \"@microsoft.graph.teamCreationMode\": \"migration\",   \"template@odata.bind\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')\",   \"displayName\": \"My Sample Migration Team\",   \"description\": \"\",   \"createdDateTime\": \"2020-03-14T11:22:17.043Z\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var GetResult = await HTTPClient.PostAsync(uri, Content.Content);
```

For both of those, I receive "Resource not found for the segment 'teams'.
Has anybody seen That? How can I acces\work with Teams resources via Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

When you call *https://graph.windows.net*, this is [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-planning-checklist) which is deprecated and will be decommissioned from June 30th 2022.

I recommend you switch over to use Microsoft Graph which you call *https://graph.microsoft.com/version*. See [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) to get started.

Check [List Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on how to list teams channels using MS Graph.